# "Cannot get Jedis connection" when using SSL with Redis and Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring, ssl, redis

I'm using SSL enabled Redis (ElasticCache from AWS), and having difficulty in connecting to it using Spring Data Redis.

(Note that the connectivity works fine, if I use plain Jedis or Jedis Pool with Spring).

Following is the code snippet:

```
    @Value("${vcap.services.myredis.credentials.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${vcap.services.myredis.credentials.password}")
    private String redisPassword;

    @Value("${vcap.services.myredis.credentials.port}")
    private String redisPort;

    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {

        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();


        String hostUri = "rediss://:" + redisPassword + "@" + redisHost + redisPort;    

        JedisShardInfo info = new JedisShardInfo(hostUri);

        JedisConnectionFactory conn =  new JedisConnectionFactory(info);

        conn.afterPropertiesSet();

        template.setConnectionFactory(conn);
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }

}
```

RedisTemplate usage:

```
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, String> redistemplate;


    public void api2() {

        HashOperations<String, Object, Object> hashOperations = redistemplate.opsForHash();

        hashOperations.put("KEY", "1", "one"); 
    }

}
```

Any operation using RedisTemplate throws below exception:

> "nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot
>   get Jedis connection; nested exception is
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool] with root cause
>   2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>   2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
>   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_141] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
>   at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2139)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na] 2018-01-22T15:59:35.531+11:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]
>   [OUT] at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:108)
>   ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]"

Note:

1. This is not an issue with SSL Certs as SSL certs for AWS are already present in the JVM Trust store and note that JedisPool is working with SSL.
2. I suspect that somehow the JedisConnectionFactory is ignoring and not making a SSL connection. I tried other arg constructors of JedisConnectionFactory like setting the useSSL to true, etc, without luck.

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `redisHost + ":"+ redisPort`?

Comment: Yes, apologies, that is a typo  while posting my code..

    String hostUri = "rediss://:" + redisPassword + "@" + redisHost + ":" + redisPort;

Comment: Does anyone have any pointers to this the above issue.. I suspect this to be a bug in Spring Data Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `JedisShardInfo` as it causes ambiguities with the configuration it carries. The constructor accepting `JedisShardInfo` is deprecated in Spring Data Redis 2.0. Use the property-based configuration instead:

```
JedisConnectionFactory conn =  new JedisConnectionFactory();
conn.setHostName(redisHost);
conn.setPort(redisPort);
conn.setUseSsl(true);
```

Comment: I tried the above as well without luck. I'm getting same exception for the above as well.

Comment: Which version of Spring Data Redis do you use?

Comment: I used 1.5.9.RELEASE of Spring Boot (and Spring Data Redis). I have tried 1.5.6.Release as well resulting in same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue however, it was with `JedisPool` and not with `Spring` and `JedisShardInfo`. I believe though, that it is essentially the same issue. When connecting to an AWS Elasticache redis cluster with SSL enabled I would get a

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

What solved my issue was using `jedis 2.9.0` and initiating my `JedisPool` like this:

```
String host = "someHost"; // The primary endpoint of the cluster
JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool("rediss://" + host + ":6379");
```

It's important to use a `String` constructor here as the `URI` one doesn't enable SSL.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned only AWS Elastic Redis, but you didn't specify whether it is Cluster based Redis or Single Node Redis ?

Spring Data Redis 2.2 will support for Cluster with SSL.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-974

Answer (score 0):

For **redis client 3.2.0** and above we can set ssl properties as follows:

Using JedisShardInfo:

```
JedisShardInfo shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo(redisServer, redisServerPort, redisTimeout, redisSsl);
shardInfo.setPassword(redisPassword);
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
```

Using JedisPool:

```
jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, redisServer, redisServerPort, redisTimeout, redisPassword, redisSsl);
jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
```

Where, in `poolConfig`, you can specify various properties like, `setMaxIdle`, `setMaxWaitMillis`, `setMaxTotal` and so on.