# JedisConnectionException - Read timed out error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jedis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I'm trying to connect to AWS ElastiCache Redis using Spring Data Redis + Jedis combination. [Redis Cluster enabled, so it has Cluster Config endpoint, with 3 shard - each shard has 1 primary node + 2 replica nodes ]

I'm getting Read timed out error.

`Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

AWS Redis Server Version : 5.0.3 /
Cluster Mode : Enabled  / 
SSL : Enabled /
Auth : Enabled ( by password )

Library -- 
Spring-data-redis : 2.1.6.Release / 
jedis : 2.9.0

Telnet works to AWS Redis all nodes and cluster config endpoint at 6379 ports.

I tried Redisson by itself, it connects to AWS Redis, with out any issue.

So, no issues with Redis itself, issue with Spring Data Redis in combination with Jedis.

My Code looks like this -

```
        RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
        redisClusterConfiguration.setClusterNodes(listOfRedisNode);
        redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword(passwordString);


        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        jedisClientConfiguration.useSsl();
        jedisClientConfiguration.usePooling();


        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration, jedisClientConfiguration.build() );
        jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        final RedisTemplate<String, Serializable> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

        System.out.println(redisTemplate.getClientList().size());

        StringRedisConnection stringRedisConnectionlettuce = new DefaultStringRedisConnection(redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection());
        final String message2 = stringRedisConnectionlettuce.echo("Hello");
        System.out.println("Hello".equals(message2));
```

Read time out error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:239)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:96)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:126)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:117)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.auth(BinaryClient.java:564)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2138)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterConnectionHandler.initializeSlotsCache(JedisClusterConnectionHandler.java:36)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterConnectionHandler.<init>(JedisClusterConnectionHandler.java:17)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.<init>(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:24)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisCluster.<init>(BinaryJedisCluster.java:54)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.<init>(JedisCluster.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:418)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createCluster(JedisConnectionFactory.java:388)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at io.github.deepshiv126.springdataredis.example.MySpringBootApplication.main(MySpringBootApplication.java:306)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:196)
    ... 27 more
```

I looked into Spring Source Code and Jedis Source Code -- My assumption its not using SSL Connection ;

JedisConnectionFactory - afterPropertiesSet()-- trying to create Cluster -- under that it's trying initializeSlotsCache, which issued AUTH command to Redis Server, with password -- This is where "Read timed out" is occuring;

I understand local redis - you can go inside and run auth command to get authenticate. But I guess AWS Redis may not able to do that , its needs to have SSL Connection even before it runs AUTH command - Why Jedis is not using SSL Connection ?

This another thread ["Cannot get Jedis connection" when using SSL with Redis and Spring Data Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493941/cannot-get-jedis-connection-when-using-ssl-with-redis-and-spring-data-redis)
says, use something like JedisPool - but spring-data-redis' JedisConnectionFactory doesn't accepts JedisPool. Is there any other way to do that ?

`JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool("rediss://" + clusterConfigEndPoint + ":6379");`

Another question - other libraries use redis ssl connection as `rediss://` - how to Jedis Client to use SSL connection,

Any help will be really appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Update : I figured out little later that Jedis didnt had capability to support Cluster Setup with SSL Connection; As a result Spring-Data-Redis also didnt support it.

Now, Jedis and Spring Data Redis both support Cluster based Redis, with SSL. 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-974

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this for quite a while, however with below configuration it works perfectly with AWS ElasticCache - Redis with SSL Enabled (Encryption-in-transit & Encryption-at-rest enabled).

Below Maven dependencies are used as part of springboot application

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Latest jedis with SSL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

@Component
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("PrimaryEndpoint of AWS Elastic Cache Cluster");
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setUsername("userName");
        
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(new String("password").toCharArray());

        JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));// 60s connection timeout
        jedisClientConfiguration.useSsl();
        jedisClientConfiguration.usePooling();

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration,
                jedisClientConfiguration.build());
        jedisConFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jedisConFactory;
    }

    @Bean(value = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }

}
```